# Clion cannot recognize header file or any keywords

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I was using Clion perfectly yesterday, but today, I opened Clion again and Clion cannot recognize any header files and keywords. It just says the header files don't exist and the keywords are "undeclared identifiers." You can see the error in this image:
[image: thing]

Then, I looked at the file clion-Debug-log.txt:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler
    “/usr/bin/cc”
  is not able to compile a simple test program.
  It fails with the following output:
    Change Dir: /Users/wmm/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-kdTUik
    Run Build Command(s):/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/ninja/mac/ninja -v cmTC_7d28b && [1/2] /usr/bin/cc   -arch arm64 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_7d28b.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/wmm/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-kdTUik/testCCompiler.c
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_7d28b.dir/testCCompiler.c.o 
    /usr/bin/cc   -arch arm64 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_7d28b.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/wmm/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-kdTUik/testCCompiler.c
    You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements. Please run 'sudo xcodebuild -license' from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode and Apple SDKs license.
```

Basically, it says the error is caused because I didn't agree to the conditions of the Xcode license. So, I followed the instruction given and entered `sudo xcodebuild -license` into my terminal. I agreed to the license, then reopened Clion, and the error is still there. I also reinstalled Clion, but the error persists.

I copy pasted parts of the message from the clion-Debug-log.txt file in google, but google says there are no results for this.

Does anyone know what is causing this error? Thank you so much!

Comment: See the errors in CMakeFiles/CMakeErrors.log. What does `xcode-select -p` show?

Comment: xcode-select -p shows "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer". In my CMakeFiles folder, there is no such file as CMakeErrors.log (I can show you a screenshot if you want)

Comment: There should be 2 files, CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log and CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log. Find the latter.

Comment: For some reason I cannot find this file. I used terminal to find it and i get "No such file or directory".

Comment: Weird, the file should be in /Users/wmm/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Friedrich: The image demonstrates red underline for included files. This aspect cannot be represented by a textual code, so the image is acceptable here.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I value your opinion. The sentence "all standard library includes are underlined with red wavy lines" would have conveyed the same information. Furthermore, I think we've all experienced situations where an IDE's visual feedback and the actual error were unrelated. IMHO, the image is fluff at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just had to 'Tools | CMake | Reset Cache and Reload Project' in CLion after agreeing to the Xcode license. Now it works fine.